# How do you change the way unlist use.names structures the names it puts together

Tags: r, list, radix

I've got a set of nested lists, such as this:

```
setoflists <- list(first.list = list(letter.a=1, letter.b=2, letter.c=3),
                   second.list = list(letter.d=4, letter.e=5, letter.f=6))
```

I want to flatten it to a single list. However, I want the names of the objects in the list to have the sublist first, then the top list, separated by an underscore "_". One reason is my list names already have lots of fullstops (.) in them.

I can flatten the list with `unlist` like so:

```
newlist <- unlist(setoflists, use.names = T, recursive = F)
```

but the names produced have top list, then sublist, separated by "."

```
> names(newlist)
[1] "first.list.letter.a"  "first.list.letter.b"  "first.list.letter.c"  "second.list.letter.d" "second.list.letter.e"
[6] "second.list.letter.f"
```

The format I want is:

```
letter.a_first.list
letter.b_first.list ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to control this using the current approach as it's calling `make.names()` as part of `unlist()`.  You probably need to rename afterwards:

```
names(newlist) <- unlist(Map(paste, lapply(setoflists, names), names(setoflists), sep = "_"))

names(newlist)

[1] "letter.a_first.list"  "letter.b_first.list"  "letter.c_first.list"  "letter.d_second.list" "letter.e_second.list"
[6] "letter.f_second.list"
```

Comment: The problem is my real top list and sublist names are more complex and already have several fullstops (.) in them. That's why I want to use _, but it's also why sub won't work easily. I'll update the example

Comment: OK - this will match on the final period though.  Try on your real data and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: > sub("(.*)\\.(.*)", "\\2_\\1", names(newlist))
[1] "a_first.list.letter"  "b_first.list.letter"  "c_first.list.letter"  "d_second.list.letter" "e_second.list.letter"
[6] "f_second.list.letter"

Comment: OK, that's a bit different from your question as first posed.  See edit.

Comment: This works nicely now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution with `regex`, following the first idea of @ritchie-sacramento:

```
setoflists <- list(firstlist = list(letter.a=1, letter.b=2, letter.c=3),
                   secondlist = list(letter.d=4, letter.e=5, letter.f=6))

newlist <- unlist(setoflists, use.names = T, recursive = F)

names(newlist) <- sub("(.*)(?:[.])(letter.+)", "\\2_\\1", names(newlist))

names(newlist)
```

Output:

```
> names(newlist)
[1] "letter.a_first.list" "letter.b_first.list" "letter.c_first.list" "letter.d_secondlist" "letter.e_secondlist" "letter.f_secondlist"
```